# Rename substring of column values of a python DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, bigdata, data-conversion

My problem: 
I have a datetime columns, with formats like

```
'27SEP18:05:02:11'
```

When trying to convert the datetime values I started like

```
df['dtimes'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dtimes'],format = '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')
```

and ran into the problem that 'SEP' is not of the form 'Sep'. Surely I would not like to loop these columns.

Any speed code suggestions, please!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%y` for match year in format `YY`, `%Y` is used for `YYYY` format:

```
#YY format of year - %y
df = pd.DataFrame({'dtimes':['27SEP18:05:02:11','27JAN18:05:02:11']})

df['dtimes'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dtimes'],format = '%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S') 
print (df)
               dtimes
0 2018-09-27 05:02:11
1 2018-01-27 05:02:11
```

---

```
#YYYY format of year - %Y
df = pd.DataFrame({'dtimes':['27SEP2018:05:02:11','27JAN2018:05:02:11']})

df['dtimes'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dtimes'],format = '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S') 
print (df)
               dtimes
0 2018-09-27 05:02:11
1 2018-01-27 05:02:11
```